# Different raster shapes even though I used the same clipping polygon (Python)

Tags: python, raster, polygon, clip, shape-area

I have a bathymetry raster image that I would like to use for masking regions where elevation > -1. I have started by clipping the bathymetry image and another target image using the same rectangular polygon. However, when checking the shape of clipped images, results seem to be slightly different:

```
img_mask = rasterio.open('\Bathymetry\spainMask\mask_1_ESP.tif')
img_mask.shape   

output: (972, 1159)

img = rasterio.open("\Rw490_ESP.tif")
img.shape

output: (972, 1160)
```

This slight difference in shape makes it impossible to apply the bathymetry mask subsequently. Is there a way to avoid this problem or to detect the pixels that do not exist in both images and remove them?

Links to clipped images:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C9SLT3mCDuLZC8ce508w70EXXguJCysu/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L0wlljxBXRsnjDf5rFClqEI4hfsMqOeL/view?usp=sharing

The code used for clipping the images:

```
ESP = gpd.read_file("\Vector\spainVector.shp")
geometry_ESP = ESP["geometry"]

clipImg, clipImg_Transform = mask(img, geometry_ESP, crop=True, invert=False)
clipImg_Meta = img.meta.copy()
clipImg_Meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                    "height": clipImg.shape[1],
                    "width": clipImg.shape[2],
                    "transform": clipImg_Transform})
outputDirectory = '\bathymetry_ESP.tif'

with rasterio.open(outputDirectory, 'w', driver='Gtiff',width=clipImg.shape[2],height=clipImg.shape[1], count=1,
                    crs=img.crs,transform=clipImg_Transform, dtype='float32') as dst:
    dst.write(clipImg)
```